How to have different props for dynamic components in react
I'm creating a react component that needs to have a different parent on the server vs the client.
const Router = runtime.isServerSide ? Server : Client;

<Router>
  <Child />
</Router>

The Server component takes different props than the Client component.
I used conditional rendering to fix this, but I'd like to be able to specify the props in the declaration for Router instead
{runtime.isServerSide ? (
  <Server serverProp={123}>
    <Child />
  </Server
) : (
  <Client clientProp={false}>
    <Child>
  </Client>
)}


A react component is essentially a function. In typescript, when you have a variable typed as a union of functions and you try to use it it essentially becomes a function with the argument typed as an intersection of the arguments of all member of the union of functions. This can be observed easily with a simple example:
const fnNumber = (v:number)=>{}
const fnString = (v:string)=>{}

const fnStringOrNumber = [fnNumber, fnString][0]

fnStringOrNumber() // v: never

Here, fnStringOrNumber expects one argument of type never.
So in your case you can't rely on the conditional expression to resolve good props for you. If you want to look more into that aspect you can have a look at Typescript union type of functions weirdly becomes an intersection type of the arguments.
But generally, in React, you may just want to have another type that represents the props for the router, than you create explicitly, and within the Router components you can chose which props to pass to which component.
For example could do something like this
type RouterProps = {
  serverProps: ComponentProps<typeof Server>;
  clientProps: ComponentProps<typeof Client>;
};

const Router = (props: RouterProps) => {
  if (isServerSide()) {
    return <Server {...props.serverProps} />;
  }
  if (!isServerSide()) {
    return <Client {...props.clientProps} />;
  }
  return null;
};


Then you're explicitly passing the right props to the components that expects them. It's a little extra work but not much, should be fine. You can use ComponentProps type to get the props from the components, which makes it easier.
Basically all you're doing is creating a new component and taking charge of the props explicitly to avoid any inference issues.
Here's a link to typescript playground that may help a bit.
Cheers.
